# Spark S3 extremely slow network download speed

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read a TSV dataset with 37K files (totaling 5-8 TB) from S3 in Spark on Apache EMR. I'm using a cluster of 91 r5d.4xlarge hosts with executor memory as 36GB and executor cores as 15. It currently takes me up to an hour to download this dataset. AWS documentation for r5d.4xlarge promises network speeds of up to 10 Gbps (ie 1.25GBps) for each host (See link below for reference). However, when I go to ganglia and select bytes_in, I see each node downloading the data at only 20 MBps. Does anyone know how I can increase my download speeds (or any other way to read the dataset quickly)? Wondering if the bottleneck is in how spark is reading the data from S3, S3 itself or that AWS over-promised me?

Thanks

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/r5/

Comment: how do you read the file?

Comment: turns out that this is the problem. We have an underlying library (owned by another team) that is suboptimally downloading the files. For each of the 37K files (which are 141-226 MB), it's splitting the individual files themselves into separate 16 MB slices and downloading each slice in a separate S3 call. I don't understand the need to slice individual files into 16 MB chunks. I'm no networking wizard but I'm guessing that downloading 16 MB itself is super quick but the overhead associated with each download maybe like 1 second and that's why I'm seeing the current speeds of 15-20 MBPS

Comment: The EMR s3 connector will have a property to set the block size -some number it gives to spark to tell it how to split up files between workers, and for this option the default is 16MB. Look at the AWS docs, find the option, set to something like 256MB and then each file will be processed as one